# solution of linear elliptic equation

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Can you please help me to show that if $\Omega\subset\mathbb R^n$ is a $C^2$ domain and $f$ is an application which belongs to $L^2(Ω)$ and $u$ is a weak solution of the linear elliptic equation:

$$\left\{\begin{array}{c}
−\Delta u = f & \text{on }\Omega \\
u(0)=u_0
\end{array}\right.,$$

if $f$ is in $C^b (Ω)$ with $b ∈ (0,1)$, then $u$ is a classical solution of the linear elliptic equation?

Here is what I did so far:

[image]

[image]

Thank you in advance.

**Note**

I guess the "sur" is French for "on", and translated accordingly. If it was supposed to be some operator I do not know of, let me know.

Comment: What is your own thoughts on the problem and what have you done so far? And use this tutorial for writing math symbols and expressions [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: If someone is willing to copy those images with proper MathJax use, he is very welcome. I am not really willing now. Looks like a rather long task…. In any case, note to poster: when asked for clarification, you should either reply to the comment by clicking "add comment", or edit the question by pressing "edit" right under the question. You can always comment on your own posts and -- I guess -- answers to your questions. Once you have sufficient -- 50, I think? -- rep, you will be able to comment on any post.

Comment: As for edits, you can always edit your own posts, and I don't know of any rep limit for suggesting edits. The edits you suggest will be placed in a Review queue where people with 2000 rep and over -- me included -- will see them and choose whether to approve them or reject them. If you ever get to 2000 rep, this suggesting edits thing will turn into direct editing, and you will be able to review suggested edits. For more info about rep and privilegies, read [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) and look around the [help center](http://math.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: Oh, and [Welcome to Math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/tour)!